# Regex to only validate numbers between -1 (minus one) and +1 (one)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to put together a regex to validate a percentage input. The input needs to validate specifically from -1(minus one) to 1(plus one) and everything in between (example: -0.85, 0.2, 0.45) is valid and anything over or under these values fails.

I have the following so far but can't work out how to restrict it to -1 to 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 const regEx = /^-?\d+(\.\d{1,9})?$/;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How many decimal places? I'm assuming just two

Comment: are 1 and -1 themselves valid?

Comment: Which programming language? `JavaScript` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?:-1|-?0(?:\.\d+)?|1)$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uzfvYf/2/).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^             # start of line
(?:           # non-capturing group
-1            # -1
|             # or
-?0(?:\.\d+)? # -0.9999 until 0.9999
|             # or
1             # 1
)
$             # end of string
```

---

Otherwise, just grab the input, convert it to a number and use some programming logic (ie `if number ...`).

Comment: @Jan `^-?(?:1|0(?:\.\d+)?)$` is faster

Comment: Should `-0` be a valid match?

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/P3oY9M/1)

```
^-?(?:1(?:\.0+)?|0(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

#### Usage

Assuming JavaScript based on your current code, but if you update to another language I'll change the code to that language.

```js
var a = [-1.0,-1,-0.85,0,0.2,0.45,1,1.0,-100,-10,-2,-1.01,1.01,2,10,100]
var r = /^-?(?:1(?:\.0+)?|0(?:\.\d+)?)$/

a.forEach(function(v) {
  if (r.exec(v) !== null) {
    console.log(v)
  }
})
```

Assuming this is also acceptable, you don't need regex:

```js
var a = [-1.0,-1,-0.85,0,0.2,0.45,1,1.0,-100,-10,-2,-1.01,1.01,2,10,100]

a.forEach(function(v) {
  if (v >= -1 && v <= 1) {
    console.log(v)
  }
})
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `-?` Optionally match `-` (allows matching negative or positive values)
- `(?:1(?:\.0+)?|0(?:\.\d+)?)` Match either of the following

  - `1(?:\.0+)?` Match the following (this matches 1, 1.0, 1.00, etc.)

    - `1` Match this literally
    - `(?:\.0+)?` Optionally match the following

      - `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
      - `0+` Match one or more `0`s literally
  - `0(?:\.\d+)?` Match the following (this matches 0.000... to 0.999...)

    - `0` Match this literally
    - `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match the following

      - `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
      - `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation! I have accepted Jan's answer because he was the first and it works well for me. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChrisA why do people accept *first*? Seems silly to me - especially considering they were posted less than a minute apart. @Jan's answer is a good one, basically shorter version of the same regex I use. The only thing it doesn't allow is `1.00`, only allows `1` (which is how both of our regexes differ - mine allows `1` to have decimal places).

Answer (score 0):

If a language parser were to validate a number between -1 and 1 it would
do it like this:

`(?m)^-?0*(?:1(?:\.0*)?|0(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$`

Formatted

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 -? 0*
 (?:
      1
      (?: \. 0* )?
   |  
      0
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  
      \. \d+ 
 )
 $
```

Matches these:

`1
-1.
-0
0.
.0
0.2
0.99
-0.333
-.999`